# Delete row from R dataframe based on individual cell values

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to use R to isolate the values in a single column in a dataframe, then comparing the value of row n to row n-1. If row n is equal to row n-1, I want to delete that row. For example:

```
ID   Time1   Time2
1    6       7
2    5       8
3    5       9
4    6       6
```

For this example focus only on the column Time1. I want to delete observation 3, because the value of Time1 in this observation is the same as in observation 2. However, I do NOT want to delete observation 4, even though the value of Time1 here is the same as in observation 1. I need the focus to be strictly on the comparison between observation n and observation n-1, not any others that come before it. Is there an easy way to make this work in R? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `df[!c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1)) == 0, ]`

Comment: Another option can be as `dfplyr::filter(df, Time1 != lag(Time1, default = -Inf))`

Comment: @CPak Thanks! This worked perfectly. If you would, can you please walk me through exactly what this code is doing? Just for my edification.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% dfplyr::filter( Time1 != lag(Time1, default = -Inf))

#   ID Time1 Time2
# 1  1     6     7
# 2  2     5     8
# 3  4     6     6
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"ID   Time1   Time2
1    6       7
2    5       8
3    5       9
4    6       6",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of code in comments

```
df[!c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1)) == 0, ]
```

Working inside out

```
diff(df$Time1)    # difference between x+1 & x position
# -1  0  1
# [5 - 6] [5- 5] [6 -5]

c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1))  # concatenates TRUE to front of numerical vector
# TRUE -1 0 1

c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1)) == 0
# FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE

!c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1)) == 0   # negate logical
# TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE

df[!c(TRUE, diff(df$Time1)) == 0, ] # subset rows that are true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the lag of `Time1` to the dataframe then filter out the rows where `Time1 == Time1_lag`.

Here's how you might do it with just base R:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, Time1 = c(6, 5, 5, 6), Time2 = c(7, 8, 9, 6))
# Remove the last observation and put an NA for the first one to create the lag
df$Time1_lag <- c(NA, df$Time1[-nrow(df)])
# need to worry about the NA in the first row, so add an extra condition
df[df$Time1 != df$Time1_lag | is.na(df$Time1_lag), ]
```

Here's how you could do it with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, Time1 = c(6, 5, 5, 6), Time2 = c(7, 8, 9, 6))
df %>% mutate(Time1_lag = lag(Time1)) %>% filter(Time1 != Time1_lag | is.na(Time1))
```